# Photos: Import All New Items doesn't work

Tags: iphone, photos

I have over 30,000 photos on my iPhone 8 Plus. Photos Library on my MacBook Pro is currently empty.

I tried to import all photos from my iPhone to the Photos app but had a lot of problems. The first few times it was stuck at around either 13,000 or 15,000 photos, now the "Import All New Items" button doesn't work at all.

I tried restarting both devices (also in safe mode), deleting the Photos Library, and creating a new one, but nothing helped.

If anyone has had a similar issue, how did you resolve it?

Comment: I think what's going to have to be done, regardless of what method, only import a few at a time, and when I say few, it's relative to the total number. So 500 ~ 1000 at a time may be.

Comment: Do you want your iPhone and MacBook Photo Libraries synced? If so, have you enabled iCloud for this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the "Import All New Items" button seemed to do nothing. It switched me to the Imports tab, but now new items would import. Clicking back on the Device tab, the progress bar was not moving and I only had the option to "Stop Import".

My Mac had fairly **low disk space**.

I deleted some items and emptied the Trash.

Then pressed "Import All New Items" again and it immediately started importing items.

[image]

Opening Console shows the errors:

```
ERROR: <private> (type: not-enough-storage-space, path: (null)), file: <private>, line: 399
```

and

```
PLCacheDeleteClient: Purged enough bytes (purged=Zero KB requested=10.86 GB): NO, Enough space now available (available=20.53 GB total needed: 31.63 GB): NO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using Image Capture on your Mac to bring the Photos over from your iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I have tried using Image Capture, but it it was repeatedly stopping in the middle and saying "Please unlock iPhone" or "No camera or scanner selected", so I then started importing again and ended up with multiple duplicates, and not all photos imported anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using an original Apple Lightning cable instead of a third-party cable.